# Can i ad a (active) sub to this simple set?

Tags: audio, speakers, subwoofer

I have [this set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBLXYU9):
[image]

(How)Can i add [this active sub](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Devine-Artis-18-inch-Active-Subwoofer/dp/B084Z6P1H7)?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Alesis manual, the 1/4" line out follows the speaker outputs, so you could run a line from there into one of the inputs on the sub (which has a built in crossover), set the sub volume appropriately, then control the overall system level with the Master level knob.